# Why does Metal constant with h suffix produce bad byte range results?

Tags: metal

I have run into a very strange problem in my Metal shader that has to do with a byte value in the range (0, 255). This byte value is represented as a ushort that is converted to a half precision by code like (x / 255.0h). What is strange is that this literal constant divide seems to be optimized incorrectly when run on a A7 device (A10 does not do this). Has anyone else run into this? Is there some way I can write Metal code that is used only on this GPU family 1 device?

I found a workaround, by leaving the h suffix off of the inline constant:

```
// This method accepts 4 byte range input values and encodes them as a half4 vector
// that works properly on A7 class hardware. The issue with A7 devices is that
// there seems to be a compler bug or range issue with an operation like (x / 255.0h).
// What should be the same operation (x / 255.0) does not show the range problem on A7.

half4
encodeBytesAsHalf4(const ushort4 b4) {
  return half4(b4.x/255.0, b4.y/255.0, b4.z/255.0, b4.a/255.0);
}
```